# How HTTP Server inform its clients that the response has ended

Tags: http, httpclient

I know that, [the http clients sends](http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-know-socket-has-end-of-http.html) `0x10` `0x13` bytes to inform the http server that the request data has finished.

But how the server informs the http clients that the response data has finished? (it sends `-1` i.e. `<EOF>` correct)?

Answer (score 3):

No. HTTP Clients do not send CRLF to the server to indicate that the request is complete, and servers do not send a particular byte sequence to the client to indicate completion. You should read this document: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4 to understand how clients and servers are able to determine when a request or response is complete. The short summary is that the Content-Length header, Chunked Transfer-encoding terminator, or TCP/IP connection closure are all used as signals.

Comment: A more recent explanation is in: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-16.html#rfc.section.3.3 -- this is intended to clarify RFC 2616 a lot.